# Browser shows &lt; and &gt; instead of <>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a very simple HTML page using the Typewriter JavaScript plugin.

The page essentially should type out the code of an elementary Java program in which each declared variable is one of my contact details.

The problem is that if I write `<span class="standard-highlight">List&lt;String&gt; list = Arrays</span>`, the browser doesn't display `List<String> list =` but instead displays `List&lt;String&gt; list =`.

How can I fix this?

Here is a snippet from the output in the browser (Chrome)
[image: Snippet from output in browser (Chrome)]

JavaScript below:

```
function setupTypewriter(t) {

var HTML = t.innerHTML;

t.innerHTML = "";

var cursorPosition = 0,
    tag = "",
    writingTag = false,
    tagOpen = false,
    typeSpeed = 10,
    tempTypeSpeed = 0;

var type = function() {

    if (writingTag === true) {
        tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }

    if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;

        if (tagOpen) {
            tagOpen = false;
            writingTag = true;
        } else {
            tag = "";
            tagOpen = true;
            writingTag = true;
            tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
        }
    }

    if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
        tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }

    if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
        if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
            tempTypeSpeed = 0;
        }
        else {
            tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 30;
        }
        t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
        tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 30;
        writingTag = false;
        if (tagOpen) {
            var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
            t.appendChild(newSpan);
            newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
            tag = newSpan.firstChild;
        }
    }

    cursorPosition += 1;
    if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
        setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
    }

  };

  return {
    type: type
  };
}

var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

typewriter.type();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: These are html entities that are encoded. You need to decode them. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Comment: Looks like you have one level of HTML-Encoding too many.

Comment: please show html snipped, since its work for me..

Comment: Are you adding this with JS? If so, just use < and >?

Comment: Please provide the code. Without that we are unable to help you.

Comment: Just added a snippet of the output in the browser

Comment: What does you javascript look like? I don't think the issue is with Java.

Comment: How do you get the string from the user? I don't see a you capturing a string anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine for me.

```
<span class="standard-highight" id="app"></span>

    <script>
    var app = document.getElementById('app');
    var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
        loop: true 
});
    typewriter.typeString('<span>List&lt;String&gt; list = Arrays</span>').start();
    </script>
```

Place the string passing to the typeString() function within any html tag and only then the HTML symbols will be rendered by the function.

Comment: this shows the <> but stops the Typewriter effect. The text becomes static.